# CSS 80% opacity on strong tag within paragraph but if no strong tag 100%

Tags: html, css

So an agency has sent me some code and I coded site with using their method in CSS with changing the opacity to 80% for `<p>` tags, however my client has picked this up and so much has been built.

I have added in `p { opacity(0.8) }` and changes paragraph tags to the same colour however I have some titles like `<p><strong>text</strong></p>` which are also now fading so my question is (without a load of work to change) is it possible in CSS that I make `<p>` that contain a strong tag use 100% ?

Rough example below:

HTML

```
<p><strong>test title</strong></p>
<p>test test here</p>
```

CSS:

```
p { opacity(0.8) }
```

However I need to ensure that `p > strong` remains with no opacity change so 100% in this case.

I know it's a sloppy fix but there's no time to re-do this all or set own classes for colour change on everything.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/8du1d12o/

Comment: Note that if these are truly titles, they shouldn't be marked up in paragraph and strong tags to begin with. They should be `h*` tags.

Comment: I agree, its how stupid design agency provide markup and styles and width a 4 day deadline and 2 weeks of work being a long 20-22hr days lol

Comment: Design agencies shouldn't be allowed to touch markup. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. If the parent is set to 80% opacity, any child element, at most, will be only 80% opaque. (I would ask why paragraphs are set to an opacity other than 1 to begin with, though...)

One potential workaround is to not use opacity, but RGBA. You could do this:

```
p { color: rgba(0,0,0,.8) } /* 80% black */
p strong { color: rgba(0,0,0,1) } /* 100% black */
```

(PS, as stated in my comment, if these are truly titles, the markup should be using header tags--not paragraph tags)

Comment: @James that's fine. I just used black in my examples. You can use white or any colors interchangeably.

Comment: I done a sloppy quick fix given deadline at 9am and now 4am but managed to get it working great from your example so thanks for that mate. ill change and recode it all at some stage next week haha

Answer (score 0):

I've looked a bit more into it and it seems like we would need to use a parent selector which css doesnt have :/

you might need to add a class to the paragraph elements or use Jquery to do a special selector to apply your desired styles

I believe the issue has to do with how opacity works, it seems to make everythings inside the div (or whatever level you set it opaque) Therefore I would think that putting the specific span tag like mentioned above would work.

Also note for people how have a similar problem setting backgrounds you can use the code below, it DOES NOT MAKE the text transparent, only the background

```
background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
```

Comment: i tried p:not(strong) { opacity(0.8) } did not seem to do the trick, would be a perfect quick solution though.

Comment: I believe the issue had to do with selecting the children, is the opacity for a background color?

Comment: @kevinn2065 the issue is that of opacity is set on a parent, it's applied to the children.

Answer (score -1):

```
p { opacity(0.8);background-color:red; }
p strong { background-color:blue; }
```

Comment: This will not achieve what the OP is asking. The STRONG tag will will have .8 opacity as it's parent is set that way.